# Easiest free setup for c# development

Tags: c#, installation

Am using windows xp sp3 on netbook and i need to compile c# programs for learning. I don't have fast computer or fast internet connection or fast money.

Can someone suggest the best way to get me going?

Thanks yous!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

http://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/

The express editions are free from Microsoft. The default download manager will resume where it ended if the download break due to bad internet connection.

If you don't have internet goto your local library and it is likely they will have internet. Coffee shops and some food places (like ihop) also have good internet.

Comment: Do I have to do something after 30 days?

Comment: You just need to register it, but it's free to do so :)

Comment: What happens if I don't register?

Comment: The Microsoft will be very sad because they're giving away software for free and you're not even bothering to register.

Comment: I'm ok with that. Just don't want them to take a picture of me thru webcam and send it to the FBI.

Comment: Nothing happens if you don't register.

Answer (score 5):

I believe the [C# command-line compile (csc.exe)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78f4aasd.aspx) is included with the .NET Framework and recent versions of Windows (not sure of XP). So if you already have the .NET Framework installed, you should not need anything else.

Comment: That is true, but Visual Studio Express is also free and much more powerful.

Comment: Sure, but software that is already installed on your machine takes less time to download, especially if you pay your Internet access by minute or volume.

Comment: The lowest Vista has csc.exe by default?

Comment: it's part of .NET, and since vista includes .NET, yes.

Comment: Thank you Sekhat, I will check on another laptop which has Vista and see if it has csc.exe installed.

Comment: vista home does not have csc.exe :(

Answer (score 4):

I also like [SharpDevelop](http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/). I'm not saying that it's easier than Visual Studio, but i find it very convenient. Indeed, given the fact, that you don't have a fast internet connection it can be even more preferable.

Answer (score 4):

If you want something more than "express" offers (which is good anyway), try [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/). It evolved from SharpDevelop, and among other things has nUnit and SVN support built in. Frequent releases and good support. Plus it'll work on a range of operating systems, or you can just host it in a VM if your choice of operating system somehow isn't supported (unlikely).

Comment: Do i still need .net installed?

Comment: @Yehonatan - it uses Mono, a parallel open source implementation of the CLI.

Answer (score 3):

[Visual C# 2008 Express Edition.](http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/)