# teaching friends son C#, easiest path to setup IDE on his laptop?

Tags: c#

I need to setup a c# ide (free) on his laptop, do I need to download the sdk or does windows 7 come with a c# compiler? (it's been a while setting something up from scratch)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Easiest free setup for c# development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2614367/easiest-free-setup-for-c-development)

Comment: Also make sure to check out [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) -- a "high-level" language without *some form of a REPL* should not be used for learning, IMOHO. (There is also the "live" area under a debugger session.)

Answer (score 5):

You can try [Visual C# 2010 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/express/Downloads/#2010-Visual-CS), it's a free version of Visual Studio for C# development, and IMHO more than enough for someone learning that you don't really need the full VS2010 package.

Answer (score 3):

Download Visual C# 2010 Express edition. It's free, you can find further information here: http://www.microsoft.com/express/Windows/

Answer (score 2):

Just use Microsoft Visual Studio Express.
http://www.microsoft.com/express/

Answer (score 2):

The [Microsoft Web Platform Installer](http://www.microsoft.com/web/downloads/platform.aspx) can be used to install [Visual Studio Express](http://www.microsoft.com/express/), and also easily install many of the other MS tools like [WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/webmatrix/).

> The Microsoft Web Platform Installer
>   3.0 (Web PI) is a free tool that makes getting the latest components of the
>   Microsoft Web Platform, including
>   Internet Information Services (IIS),
>   SQL Server Express, .NET Framework and
>   Visual Web Developer easy.

Similarly [Linqpad](http://www.linqpad.net/) is a great tool for playing around and dynamic prototyping. I can't advocate it enough.

> ... LINQPad is more than just a LINQ
>   tool: it's an ergonomic C#/VB
>   scratchpad that instantly executes any
>   C#/VB expression, statement block or
>   program with rich output formatting –
>   the ultimate in dynamic development.
>   Put an end to those hundreds of Visual
>   Studio Console projects cluttering
>   your source folder!

Answer (score 1):

Look for the free version of Visual Studio 2008.  Not sure if there is one for 2010.  It's at the Microsoft site. http://www.microsoft.com/express/downloads/#2008-Visual-CS

Comment: There actually is a 2010 version, so I would recommend to use that instead. See BoltClock's response.

Answer (score 1):

Framework is sufficient, IIRC.